# CHttpFile recurring or multiple calls to SendRequest()/Read() will give outdated data

Tags: rest, http, mfc

as said in the title, I´m executing CHttpFile::SendRequest() and Read() in consecutive order in a loop to fill and retrieve data through a webserver.

No errors are reported by QueryInfoStatusCode() and the data is stored by the webserver in the expected way.

However, the Read() method allways returns the same string which should be an  answer to the processed data.

Question: what am I missing here ? Must I clear the readbuffer of CHttpFile in any way ? Can it be an flaw in the webserver´s implementaion ?

INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE - flag is allready provided to CInternetSession() and OpenRequest() calls ...

If I call CHttpConnection::OpenRequest() / CHttpFile::Close() **in** the loop, everything is ok but very time consuming ...

```
    CInternetSession inetSession( "me", 1, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE);

    CHttpConnection* pInetHttpConnection = 
        inetSession.GetHttpConnection( "awebserver.com", INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD | INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE, INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT, "", "");

    CHttpFile* pHttpFile = pInetHttpConnection->OpenRequest( CHttpConnection::HTTP_VERB_POST,
        "/a/service/register", NULL, 1, NULL, NULL,
        INTERNET_FLAG_EXISTING_CONNECT | 
        INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE |
        INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID |
        INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID);

    pHttpFile->AddRequestHeaders( "content-type=application/json;charset=UTF-8");

    for( int counter = 0; counter != 10; counter++)
    {
        // build the cargo ...
        //-----------------------
        CString data; 
        data.Format( "{ \"value\" : %d }", counter);

        pHttpFile->SendRequest( NULL, 0, (LPVOID)(LPCTSTR) data, data.GetLength());

        DWORD dwRet;
        pHttpFile->QueryInfoStatusCode( dwRet);
        ASSERT( dwRet == 200);

        // read the answer ...
        //--------------------------
        char szInfoBuffer[ 4096]; 

        DWORD dwFileSize;   
        DWORD dwInfoBufferSize = sizeof( szInfoBuffer);

        pHttpFile->QueryInfo( HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_LENGTH, (void*) szInfoBuffer, &dwInfoBufferSize,NULL);  // always returns the same (correct) size, does not grow eventualy

        CString result;
        LPTSTR pBuffer = result.GetBufferSetLength( dwFileSize);

        UINT nRead = pHttpFile->Read( pBuffer, dwFileSize);
        while(nRead > 0)
        {
            pBuffer += nRead; dwFileSize -= nRead;
            nRead = pHttpFile->Read( pBuffer, dwFileSize);
        }
        result.Releasebuffer();

        TRACE( result); // Always returns { "stored" : 0 } instead of { "stored" : 1 }, { "stored" : 2 }, { "stored" : 3 } etc.
    }
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Your use of the `result` buffer is wrong. This is from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class#getbuffersetlength): *"If you use the pointer returned by GetBufferSetLength to change the string contents, call `ReleaseBuffer` to update the internal state of `CsimpleStringT` before you use any other `CSimpleStringT` methods."*

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but this isn´t a problem here since "result" is on the stack...
Any clues why the code aside of that does not give me the expected data ?

Comment: The code is accessing a `CString` object whose internal state may be incorrect. It doesn't matter where it is allocated. Since you are using an object outside its documented specification to verify correctness of code, you may well be looking at a false negative, i.e. the code works as expected, but your verification doesn't. You're going to have to make sure, that your verification works.

Comment: I cleaned the CString mess up and - no suprise - the result is the same.
I´m still wondering if this might be a flaw in the remote webserver or a missunderstanding on my side, on how REST works....

Comment: Don't post fake code. `buffer` is undeclared.